Polars transform meta data of expressions
Is it possible in python polars to transform the root_names of expression meta data?
E.g. if I have an expression like
expr = pl.col("A").dot(pl.col("B")).alias("AdotB")

to add suffixes to the root_names, e.g. transforming the expression to
pl.col("A_suffix").dot(pl.col("B_suffix")).alias("AdotB_suffix")

I know that expr.meta.root_names() gives back a list of the column names, but I could not find a way to transform them.

There is an example in the tests that does query plan node rewriting in Python with callbacks:

https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/blob/main/py-polars/tests/unit/lazyframe/cuda/test_node_visitor.py

But I can't see any equivalent API for rewriting expressions?
Out of interest, there is .serialize() which can dump to JSON.
expr.meta.serialize(format="json")

# '{"Alias":[{"Agg":{"Sum":{"BinaryExpr":{"left":{"Column":"A"},"op":"Multiply","right":{"Column":"B"}}}}},"AdotB"]}'
#    ^^^^^                                         ^^^^^^^^^^                             ^^^^^^^^^^        ^^^^^

Technically, you could modify the Alias and Column values, and .deserialize() back into an expression.
def suffix_all(expr, suffix):
    def _add_suffix(obj):
        if "Column" in obj:
            obj["Column"] = obj["Column"] + suffix
        if "Alias" in obj:
            obj["Alias"][-1] +=  suffix
        return obj 
    ast = expr.meta.serialize(format="json")
    new_ast = json.loads(ast, object_hook=_add_suffix)

    return pl.Expr.deserialize(json.dumps(new_ast).encode(), format="json")

df = pl.DataFrame({"A_suffix": [2, 7, 3], "B_suffix": [10, 7, 1]})

expr = pl.col("A").dot(pl.col("B")).alias("AdotB")

df.with_columns(expr.pipe(suffix_all, "_suffix"))

shape: (3, 3)
┌──────────┬──────────┬──────────────┐
│ A_suffix ┆ B_suffix ┆ AdotB_suffix │
│ ---      ┆ ---      ┆ ---          │
│ i64      ┆ i64      ┆ i64          │
╞══════════╪══════════╪══════════════╡
│ 2        ┆ 10       ┆ 72           │
│ 7        ┆ 7        ┆ 72           │
│ 3        ┆ 1        ┆ 72           │
└──────────┴──────────┴──────────────┘

Which does seem to "work" in this case, but the serialize docs do contain a warning:

Serialization is not stable across Polars versions

And it's probably just not a recommended approach in general.
